# Should this be conditional or biconditional?

Tags: logic, propositional-calculus, predicate-logic

> You can access Internet from campus only if you are a CS major or you
>   are not a freshman

How can the above English sentence be translated into a logical expression?

I think this is biconditional but in the book by Kenneth Rosen (7th edition, example 12 on page 11), it is written as conditional.

My solution is the following:

> P = You can access Internet. Q = CS major. R = Freshman. So, it should be
>   P <=> (Q + !R)

But in the book it is written as P => (Q + !R)

What seems like the correct answer?
I know that conditional is a subset of biconditional. But shouldn't biconditional be the stricter solution?

Comment: Whoever is downvoting, can you please leave a comment on what is wrong with the question?

Comment: "$p$ only if $q$" means "if $p$ then $q$".

Comment: Further, "$p \Leftrightarrow q$" is "$p$ **if and only if** $q$".$$\begin{array}{ll}p\Leftarrow q & p\textsf{ if }q\\p\Rightarrow q & p\textsf{ only if }q\\p \Leftrightarrow q & p\textsf{ if and only if }q\end{array}$$

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The statement says that you can access internet from campus only if you are a CS major or you are not a freshman. This can be rewritten as an if-then statement: "If you can access the internet then you are a CS major or a freshman". As these are the ONLY ways of being able to access the internet. So if you have access to the net then you must be a CS major or not a freshman, as these are the only two groups of people who are ever allowed on the internet. The statement is not saying that "If you are a CS major or if you are not a freshman then you can access the internet." Being a CS major or not a freshman is a necessary but not a sufficient condition for access to the net. So in conclusion $$P\to (Q \lor \neg R)$$
Is correct. Comment if you need more clarification.

Comment: For example you could be a CS major who hasn't signed the usage agreement contract so you're not allowed to access the net yet.

Comment: got it, thanks :)